# powershell Get-Counter -ComputerName parameter on Windows 7

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When I try to use the Get-Counter cmdlet on Windows 7 running as administrator I get the following error.

```
Get-Counter -computername "$env:ComputerName" '\Memory\Available MBytes'

Get-Counter : Unable to connect to the specified computer or the computer is of
fline.
At line:1 char:12
+ Get-Counter <<<<  -computername "$env:ComputerName" '\Memory\Available MBytes
'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Ge
   tCounterCommand
```

This same command works when I try it on XP 64 as is and also on Windows 7 when I exclude the -computername parameter.

Any idea on how to get this to work on Windows 7 with the computername parameter?

Thanks

Comment: `-ComputerName` is for connecting to a remote computer. You don't need to specify it to get the counter from the local machine.

Comment: Thanks Andy,  I am trying to use the same script for both local and remote.  That is another thing that confuses me,  it works for remote computers but not local.  I also tried disabling the loop back check.  Which did not work.

Comment: `$env:ComputerName` will always be the local computer name so it would never work for remote computers.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  I used the $env:ComputerName to simplify the example.  I am actually calling the Get-Counter cmdlet from a function that takes $server as a parameter.

Comment: I tried `-ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME` on 2003 and like XP it worked so I tried disabling the firewall on Win 7 and that didn't help either. Not sure why the difference...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can omit the -computername parameter and path the counters directly:

```
 get-counter "\\$env:computername\Memory\Available MBytes"
```

and that seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Set-Counter` does not work with `-ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME` put some logic in your function that does something similar to this:

```
function Get-ServerCounter {
    param ($Server)

    if ($env:COMPUTERNAME -eq $Server) {
        Get-Counter -Counter '\Memory\Available MBytes'        
    } else {
        Get-Counter -computername $Server -Counter '\Memory\Available MBytes'
    }
}
```

Comment: this works,  still would like to try to figure out what the underlying cause of the problem was though.

Comment: Yea, kinda a work around... Not sure what's going on since it works on XP/2003... You might want to submit the issue [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell).

Comment: looks like someone beat me to it.  http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/668897/using-get-counter-with-parameter-computername-does-not-work  but it got dismissed as not repro

Comment: Since I was able to repro with your example I noted it on the connect page you found.

Answer (score 0):

It if unfortunate. Many other cmdlets still allow you to specify the local computername with -Computername, but apparently not Get-Counter. On the other hand, the best practice for performance monitoring is to do it remotely anyway.

```
Get-Counter -computername (get-content computers.txt) '\Memory\Available MBytes'
```

Comment: thanks Jeffery,  I understand monitoring remotely is the better practice.  The reason for wanting to do it locally is trying to reproduce the issue with the app deployed on a developers image.  It seems like there must be something going on with Windows 7 that that I am missing because it works on XP,  and it also works on Windows 7 for Get-Counter -ComputerName "$env:ComputerName" -ListSet "*"