# Get-Counter not working on remote host

Tags: powershell, remote-server, performancecounter

I am trying to collect performance counters from a remote machine using PowerShell 3 and 4 on Windows 8.1/Windows Server 2008 R2 with no success.

```
Get-Counter "\\$env:computername\Memory\Available MBytes"
```

The above works for local machine only and giving error "computer is offline" on remote machine (referred to [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336258/powershell-get-counter-computername-parameter-on-windows-7)).

Also tried by using following format e.g (referred to [following link](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/31/how-i-use-powershell-to-collect-performance-counter-data)):

```
$listOfMetrics = @(
    "\processor(0)\% processor time",            
    "\processor(1)\% processor time",            
    ...            
);
```

This returns only 1st counter details and ignores others on remote machine but the same command returns all the counters on local machine. Can anyone provide any pointers to resolve this issue?

Comment: According to [PoSh V3 Doc](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/blob/staging/reference/3.0/Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics/Get-Counter.md) `Get-Counter` has already the separate parameter `-ComputerName`  and here it works.

Comment: I have tried with ComputerName parameter as well but it is not working for remote computer.

Comment: I have full permissions and I am the admin on the remote machine. Able to run other PowerShell commands and scripts remotely successfully. The issue is only with Get-Counter.

Comment: Sorry, didn't folllow the links from begin.